# Change a navigation link in SharePoint 2010

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar, links

I have been tasked with changing a sub site name in our SharePoint 2010. The name change was easy, however the top link bar still links to the incorrect name. So I then went to "Top link bar" under "Look and Feel", however the links are different to that of the top link bar.
I have attempted to visit look and feel from the main site and all sub sites and I cannot find the main link bar.

edit* If it helps my main menu bar looks like this
[image]
and as soon as I go to [Site Actions] > [Site Settings] it changes to the following
[image]
...and of course my top link edit only sees the second menu.

Comment: What happens if you browse to [SiteURL]/_layouts/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx ?

Comment: "An unexpected error has occurred. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44407/discussion-between-lee-winter-and-benny-skogberg).

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end with help from Benny

My different menus were due to a predecessor creating a custom SiteMapProvider for one of the Master pages. This Provider was declared in the web.config in the route of the site. The actual sitemap however was stored on a different drive in the ControlTemplates location...

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033
```

When I editted the top links it would revert to the built in provider and edit links as normal so nothing ever changed.

Morale of the story:- Get sharepoint designer and check the actual xml to see what SiteMapProvider your SiteMapDataSource is using in the Master page.